# Dismiss the popover when I tap a row in a tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4, uipopovercontroller

I am working on the Popover controller where I create a  popover control on the click of a button and then navigate to the class where it displays a table view in a popover class.

Here I want to dismiss the pop over when I tap a table view row.

Here is my code:

```
//popoverclass.h
UIPopoverController *popover; 
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIPopoverController *popover;

//popoverclass.m
-(IBAction)ClickNext
{
    ClassPopDismiss *classCourse = [[ClassPopDismiss alloc] init];
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:classCourse];
    popover.delegate = self;
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(50,-40, 200, 300) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
    [classCourse release];

}

//ClassPopDismiss.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PopOverClass *objclass=[[PopOverClass alloc]init];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  [objclass.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

The above code is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to dismiss popover from the same class, because the popover is presented from the class `popoverclass.m` and your table is in `ClassPopDismiss.m` .

So the best option is to have a custom delegate method in your `ClassPopDismiss.h`:

```
// ClassPopDismiss.h
@protocol DismissDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didTap;

@end
```

And set an `id <DismissDelegate> delegate;` in your `@interface` section.

Call `didTap` to tell `PopOverClass` that `tableView` is tapped.

```
// ClassPopDismiss.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [delegate didTap];
}
```

In your `popoverclass.h`:

```
@interface PopOverClass : UIViewController <DismissDelegate>
```

In your `popoverclass.m`, don't forget to assign delegate to `self`. Like:

```
ClassPopDismiss *classpop = [[ClassPopDismiss alloc]init];
classpop.delegate=self;
```

And while using the protocol method:

```
-(void)didTap
{
    //Dismiss your popover here;
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(popover != nil) {
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

What you're doing is allocating a new popover and dismissing it right away, that not working.

Answer (score 0):

Small code update for this (imho) :

```
// firstViewController.h
@interface firstViewController : UIViewController <SecondDelegate>
{
   SecondViewController *choice;
}

// firstViewController.m
- (void)choicePicked(NSString *)choice
{
   NSLog(choice);
   [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; //(put it here)
   _popover = nil; (deallocate the popover)
   _choicePicker = nil; (deallocate the SecondViewController instance)
}

// secondViewController.h (the one that will give back the data)
@protocol SecondDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)choicePicked:(NSString *)choice;
@end
@interface secondViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SecondDelegate> delegate;
@end

// secondViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selection = [_yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[self delegate] choicePicked:selection];
}
```